# Get list of product ids which are being indexed when catalog_product_price indexer is executed in 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, indexer

Want to get the list of products/SKUs which are being indexed when the following index command is executed?

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
```

Looking for any public method or observer would be helpful.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: well... when running that command, all product prices are indexed.

Comment: Thanks, @Marius does that happen (all product prices) all the time or only for the needy products?

Comment: yep, I'm pretty sure everything gets update. The price index rebuilds everything in a separate cloned table to now screw up the selects from the frontend, and when everything is done in that temporary table, the main index table is swapped with the temporary one